# Elixir: Convert a list into a map with integer keys

Tags: list, dictionary, zip, elixir

How do you go from a list: `~w[dog cat sheep]`

to a map with integer keys: `%{1=> "dog", 2=> "cat", 3=> "sheep"}`

*My Attempt:*

```
iex(1)> list = ~w[dog cat sheep]
["dog", "cat", "sheep"]
iex(2)> list |> Enum.with_index|>Enum.map(fn({a,b})->{b+1,a} end)|> Enum.into %{}

%{1=> "dog", 2=> "cat", 3=> "sheep"}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner version:

```erlang
for {v, k} <- ~w[dog cat sheep] |> Enum.with_index, into: %{}, do: {k+1, v}
```

And here's the same thing as a reusable function in a module:

```erlang
defmodule Example do
  def to_indexed_map(list, offset \\ 0)
      when is_list(list)
      and is_integer(offset),
    do: for {v, k} <- list |> Enum.with_index,
      into: %{},
      do: {k+offset, v}
end
```

Example usage:

```erlang
iex> list = ~w[dog cat sheep]
["dog", "cat", "sheep"]
iex> Example.to_indexed_map(list)
%{0 => "dog", 1 => "cat", 2 => "sheep"}
```

**Minor Update:** A less concise, but more performant version (roughly 2x faster) is shown below.

```erlang
defmodule Example do
  def to_indexed_map(list, offset \\ 0)
      when is_list(list)
      and is_integer(offset),
    do: to_indexed_map(list, offset, [])

  defp to_indexed_map([], _k, acc),
    do: :maps.from_list(acc)
  defp to_indexed_map([v | vs], k, acc),
    do: to_indexed_map(vs, k+1, [{k, v} | acc])
end
```

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for addition to Enum. Would also be nice if we could set an offset on your to_indexed_map function

Comment: @CharlesO I think I added the offset option at the same time you submitted your suggested edit, but I don't think I accepted your edit properly :-/  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: please any hint as to why the second version is more performat?

Comment: @CharlesO I suspect because the first implementation loops over the key/value pairs at least 3 times: (1) [`Enum.with_index/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/1) (2) the for comprehension (3) [`Enum.into/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#into/3). The second implementation loops twice: (1) tail-call recursion to build list (2) [`:maps.from_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#from_list-1) which is a [BIF](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.1.5/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.c#L263-L296).

Answer (score 1):

> ["dog", "cat", "sheep"]
> |> Enum.with_index(1)
> |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {item, index}, acc -> Map.put(acc, index, item) end)

returns

> %{1 => "dog", 2 => "cat", 3 => "sheep"}

Here using Enum.with_index(1) to start key with index 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).